Razorpay Web Integration : not showing all payment methods

I'm following the docs of Razorpay integration and it works but I'm not getting all my payment methods the are just popping and disappearing.
I'm getting following errors in my console:

"use client";
import React from "react";
import Script from "next/script";
import initiate from "@/actions/paymentaction";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const Payment = ({}) => {
  let toastoptions = {
    position: "top-right",
    autoClose: 1000,
    hideProgressBar: false,
    closeOnClick: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    draggable: true,
    progress: undefined,
    theme: "dark",
  };
 

  const pay = async (amt, category, CourseName) => {
    let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    if (!token) return toast.warning("Login to continue", toastoptions);
    let decoded = jwt.decode(token);
    console.log(decoded);
    let res = await initiate(decoded.username, amt, category, CourseName);
    var options = {
      key: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RAZORPAY_ID, // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
      amount: "50000", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
      currency: "INR",
      name: "Focus Hub",
      description: "Test Transaction",
      image: "https://focus-hub-xi.vercel.app/favicon.ico",
      order_id: res.id, //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
      callback_url: "https://eneqd3r9zrjok.x.pipedream.net/",
      prefill: {
        name: "Gaurav Kumar",
        email: "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
        contact: "9000090000",
      },
  
      notes: {
        address: "Razorpay Corporate Office",
      },
      theme: {
        color: "#3399cc",
      },
      
    };
    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp1.open();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></Script>
      <button
        className="lg:w-1/3 w-[80%] text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg"
        onClick={() => pay("100", "ABC", "ABC")}
      >
        Buy Course
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Payment;

This is the button I tried config but it does not work. What can I try next?
